# This SQL 'ORDER BY' is not working properly

Tags: sql

`SELECT test_column FROM test_table ORDER BY test_column` gives me this:

```
1
12
123
2
3
```

Why not:

```
1
2
3
12
123
```

How can I sort strings like numbers?

Comment: You are ordering by string and not by value.

Comment: What type si column test_column ?

Comment: Do something like SELECT test_column FROM test_table ORDER BY convert(int,test_column)

Comment: If type of `test_table` is string based, The `ORDER BY` sorts them based on first character ASCII code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT test_column 
FROM test_table 
ORDER BY cast(test_column as int)
```

But you should look into changing the column types to the correct ones.

Comment: Worth noting that `CAST` will not use any index.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
ORDER BY cast(test_column as SIGNED)
```

here, `cast` function convert value from string to integer(SIGNED) then it applied ORDER BY. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32844785/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: added cast function brief explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the type of the column is *varchar* or something similar. It looks like it is being ordered by string value, not by numeric value. If the column only contains numbers it should better be of type *int*.

Answer (score 2):

The sort is working. It's a lexicographic sort (alphabetical). It appears that that column has a text (char, varchar, ...) type, so the ordering you'll get is textual and not numeric.

If you want a numerical sort, use a numeric column type (e.g. int). (Or cast the column appropriately.)

Answer (score 0):

I think , we need to do the `cast` as part of the `select` statement , because if we use `distinct` then casting in the `order by` statement does not work:

```
  SELECT cast(test_column as int) as test_column 
    FROM test_table
ORDER BY test_column
```

and

```
  SELECT DISTINCT cast(test_column as int) as test_column 
    FROM test_table 
ORDER BY test_column
```

Comment: you are repeating what's in the accepted answer from 10 years ago.....you are contributing nothing of value.

Comment: My concern was only with distinct keywords.It is my mistake to do comment instead of reply on accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the field type in the database table to int, because it's treated as string that is why