# Order by does not work as expected

Tags: hive

I want to use `order by` command on a table to get timestamps in order. But it does not give the result I expect. For example;

```
select * from my_table order by tstmp desc;
```

I gives the result something like;

```
my_table.tstmp
--------------
     100
      98
      45
     150
     145
```

What is the reason of this and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762639/sql-order-by-not-working-properly
I think it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are taking datatype as timestamp for the column my_table.tstmp than it should contain format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss .If they are in another format declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.
And than apply your sorting.