# SQL ORDER BY - Why is it not working here?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

This is the table I have:

```
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| date                | sku    | quantity |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123333 |        2 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123333 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123333 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123337 |        2 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123335 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123331 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123332 |        2 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123333 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123334 |        1 |
| 2017-08-23 14:58:00 | 123334 |        3 |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
```

I would like to perform an select statement as follows:

```
select sku,sum(quantity) as 'total quant' from transactions
where DATE(date) between '2017-07-23' and '2017-09-23'
group by sku
order by quantity desc;
```

But I am getting this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| sku    | total quant |
+--------+-------------+
| 123332 | 2           |
| 123337 | 2           |
| 123333 | 5           |
| 123334 | 4           |
| 123335 | 1           |
| 123331 | 1           |
+--------+-------------+
```

Which is NOT in the order as I am expecting. **Why is order by not working here?**

**SIDE NOTE** My `quantity`column is of data type `int` and I have tried casting as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762639/sql-order-by-not-working-properly) but to no avail.

Comment: Don't you want to order by total quant instead ?

Comment: That ORDER BY is invalid. Should raise an error...

Comment: Do `ORDER BY 'total quant' desc`.

Comment: @jarlh - the joy of MySQLs "do anything, no matter how sane, just to be able to return a result set" philosophy, as opposed to most other database systems "that's clearly not what you wanted to do, have an error"

Comment: @jarlh I tried `order by 'total quant'` but it did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ordering by quantity.  Because it is not aggregated, you are getting an arbitrary value from each group.  You need to order by the total.  One method is:

```
order by sum(quantity) desc
```

However, I would recommend assigning a reasonable alias (one that doesn't need to be escaped) and using that:

```
select sku,sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from transactions
where DATE(date) between '2017-07-23' and '2017-09-23'
group by sku
order by total_quantity desc;
```

Comment: I got it, But why does it not recognize `order by 'total quant
'`? Why does it fail in escaping?

Comment: Thanks for explaining but may you  shade light on `arbitrary value on each group`. Do you mean the variable `quantity` is given assigned some values that are not in the resulset?

Comment: @Giovanrich You should use backticks to escape column names and aliases. Single quotes create literal strings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: @Giovanrich There's no `quantity` in the resultset, that column is just in the table rows. For each group, it selects `quantity` from an arbitrary row and orders by that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to order it by the `SUM(quantity)`.

```
SELECT sku, SUM(quantity) AS 'total quant' 
FROM transactions
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2017-07-23' AND '2017-09-23'
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
order by sum(quantity)
```