# SQL Server - SELECT statement with Variable and SUM() method

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

EDIT:

*Will try to explain in more detail this time as best as I can. I tried to make the query a bit simpler thinking it would make it easier to understand but it might have been a bad move.*

I'm trying to get the **PK_Queue** and **FK_Queue_Milestone** from the 1st row of my **Queue** table ordered by **PriorityScore DESC** and **TimeAdded ASC**

I only want to get the first row, but I was advised to not use **TOP(1)** because it would result to another SELECT being made to my original select.

This is the query that I have:

```
SELECT
@Local_PK_Queue = Q.PK_Queue,
@Local_PK_Milestone_Validate = Q.FK_Queue_Milestone

FROM dbo.Queue AS Q 

INNER JOIN @Local_PKHolderTable AS P
ON Q.FK_Queue_Process = P.PK_Process
AND Q.FK_Queue_Milestone = P.PK_Milestone
AND Q.FK_Queue_QueueType = P.PK_QueueType

WHERE Q.FK_Queue_Milestone = P.PK_Milestone
AND Q.FK_Queue_Process = P.PK_Process
AND Q.Tags LIKE '%' + @Input_Tags + '%'
AND ((FK_Queue_State = 5 AND TimeDeferred < GETUTCDATE()) OR (FK_Queue_State = 1))
AND Q.FK_Queue_Robot IS NULL
AND Q.FK_Queue_QueueType = P.PK_QueueType

ORDER BY
Q.PriorityScore DESC,
Q.TimeAdded
```

When I try to run the query, it doesn't seem to be ordering it properly because it **always gets the last row** of my table.

So did some research and stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878330/sql-order-by-why-is-it-not-working-here) here.

It seems to be the same problem that I am experiencing but using MySQL instead of SQL Server.

**TLDR: Want to ORDER BY Priority Score DESC and TimeAdded, but is not    working properly**

Comment: You need a GROUP BY!

Comment: Add `GROUP BY PK_Test`

Comment: _In a separate post here, I read that I need to use the SUM command in order to ORDER BY int columns._ Could you link to that post as this statement doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: It is because you are using SUM which is an aggregate that you need to group the data by PK_Test.

Comment: what do you want to happen?  Give more details and example with a small amount of data

Comment: You should explain the original problem instead of problems you're having with the solution. Perhaps you just want a `TOP 1` and not the SUM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would write this as:

```
SELECT @var = PK_Test, @var2 = SUM(PriorityScore)
FROM Queue
GROUP BY PK_Test
ORDER BY SUM(PriorityScore);
```

This is very strange, though, because the `GROUP BY` presumably returns multiple rows and you presumably want only one.  I might suspect that you really want to assign the variables to the highest priority scores:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @var = PK_Test, @var2 = SUM(PriorityScore)
FROM Queue
GROUP BY PK_Test
ORDER BY SUM(PriorityScore) DESC;
```